# Stuck in White screen after payment process in PayUMoney

Tags: java, android, payumoney

Using test mode PayUMoney does not work properly.

The app is stuck on a white screen after the payment process and does not do a success nor failure response.

Comment: I usually recommend including questions in your questions, there isn't one here, just a statement of what is happening. If you are going to ask a question, make sure it's one that makes sense (as in, if you ask why your code doesn't work, post the code)...

Comment: Post your code for better understanding.